# How to prevent concurrency issues in postgres with simultaneous requests for max (postgres) (sequelize)

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am currently implementing a Multi-tenant system where I have this database model called application which has it's ID and an `organziationId` which ties an application to an organization, what I want to achieve is for each application to have an `applicationOrgIndex` wherein I can generate indexes for each application with an organization. (for what I am implementing the standards require me to have a numeric index which starts at 1). so for example organization 1's first credential shall have applicationOrgIndex 1 and organization 2's first index shall also have applicationOrgIndex 1.

I was thinking of using a hook like this with transactions, does this solve the problem where two simultaneous requests can cause two applications within the same organizationId to have the same applicationOrgIndex? if so how do I prevent it? do I need table level locking to achieve this? or if there are any other ways to get to it.

```
hooks: {
  beforeCreate: async (application, options) => {
    const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

    try {
      const maxIndex = await Application.max('applicationOrgIndex', {
        where: { organizationId: application.organizationId },
        transaction
      });

      application.applicationOrgIndex = (maxIndex || 0) + 1;

      await transaction.commit();
    } catch (error) {
      await transaction.rollback();
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is you want separate, independent sequences of identifiers within one model/table, one for each application of each organisation. You can set up a separate model/table to hold the current max id for each app of each org and whenever you need a new id, briefly lock the record of that organisation's particular app `for no key update` and increment it.

Comment: @Zegarek Thank you. Yes, you have understood my usecase correctly, I will be glad to try this keep you posted, thank you very much!

Comment: If you need to not have any gaps then you also need to disallow a second attempt to create until the previous attempt is confirmed successful (and not have any deletions of course)

Comment: You can also use [advisory locks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75390456/5298879): each agent basically raises the flag saying "I'm now incrementing this org's, that app's id" and whoever tries to do that concurrently and requests the same advisory lock, has to wait in a queue. That'd use the db as only a broker, leaving you to implement the sequence handling however, wherever. Here are some a similar threads, although purely SQL: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77509146/5298879), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77855222/5298879), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77953276/5298879).